# What is the preferred/standard way to save general app settings on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there a built-in settings provider that can automatically bind to a UI or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to store a general app setting is LocalSettings here is how

```cs
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["MySetting1"] = "this is setting 1";
localSettings.Values["MySetting2"] = "Setting 2";
```

for details check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx)